# How to set height of react-select component to 100%?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I placed a Select component inside of a div, which changes it's height depending on a screen size. I need for Select to always occupy the full height of a div. Basically I want select to follow the height of its parent div. So far I tried using styles property but it doesn't work with percentage values.

```
<Select           
    options={options} 
    ...
    styles={{
    control: base => ({
        ...base,
        height: '100%',
      })
    }}
 />
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried . Its difficult to help without seeing any code .

Comment: My apologies, here's what I've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Well, too many ways. I suggest to check [here](https://react-select.com/props) for the best option. It is a react-select props list. Check it and find whether or not there is a `prop` for height or size.

As there are not enough details, this is the only help I can offer.

Comment: I can't find any other way to set height other than using styles prop. The problem is it completely ignores percent values

Comment: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1322. Check it. I think you can solve it by updating css variable. Not sure whether or not you can use 100%, but worthy try.